# style die() error message

Tags: php, error-handling, die

How do I make the `die()` message to echo in a certain place in the HTML section of the same page?

```
$files = array();
  $upload = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    foreach($upload as $uploaded){
if(!empty($uploaded)) {
if(isset($uploaded)){
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime= finfo_file($finfo, $uploaded);
  switch($mime) {
  case 'application/pdf':
  break;
  default:
die('pdf file only.');     
break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Switch with only one case is a bit silly.

Comment: In this case you should not be using `die()`, write some proper error handling if you'd like some portion of the execution to occur after the error. `die()` should only be used [in production] in the case of a catastrophic error where execution *cannot* and *should not* continue.

Comment: @Juhana but it's a good point when starting to extend the application

Answer (score 2):

`die` will immediately stop execution and send anything in buffers to the browser.

Personally, I like to do something like this:

```
function halt($str="") {
    if( $str) echo "<div class=\"server_notice\">".$str."</div>";
    require("template/foot.php");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about don't just use die, do something to insert html there and then die.

Alternatively, you have `register_shutdown_function` (Documentation: http://php.net/manual/es/function.register-shutdown-function.php) which will allow you to do things right after the script is ended with `die;`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. `die()` or `exit()` will stop executing of your script.

Thouh, you can make some error reporting system.
`$lastError = null`

Then do what you want and set this error.

Then you can check it in some place:

```
if ($lastError == 2){
  echo "The file is no in PDF format" ;
} //and so on.
```

Also you could create some constants like:

```
define("ERROR_WRONG_FORMAT", 2); //Make the error clear.
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to echo out div tags and then position them using CSS.

```
die('<div id="error">pdf file only.</div>');
```

Then add the following text to your CSS:

```
#error{position:absolute;top:10;left:10;}
```

You'll need to change the top and left values depending on where you wnat them to be.

If you don't know what CSS is, I suggest you watch TheNewBoston's tutorials on YouTube!